# How to loop my Current VBA Code

Tags: vba, excel

I need to modify with loop my existing VBA. I have a part of website link in Column A. I want to dynamic below this line.

```
ticjername = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
```

I need to loop it, because I want to continue this code until data found in Column A.
My Code:

```
Sub Macro1()
'
' Macro1 Macro
'
' Keyboard Shortcut: Ctrl+q
'

Dim ticjername As String
ticjername = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value
mURL$ = "http://www.example.com=" & ticjername
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:= _
        "URL;" & mURL, Destination:=Range("B1"))
        .Name = " "
        .FieldNames = True
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = False
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .WebSelectionType = xlSpecifiedTables
        .WebFormatting = xlWebFormattingNone
        .WebTables = "1"
        .WebPreFormattedTextToColumns = True
        .WebConsecutiveDelimitersAsOne = True
        .WebSingleBlockTextImport = False
        .WebDisableDateRecognition = False
        .WebDisableRedirections = False
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
    End With

 Columns("B:C").Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlToLeft
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks).Select
    Selection.Delete Shift:=xlUp
    Range("B1").Select
    Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
    Selection.Cut
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    ActiveCell.Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Offset(1).Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi.  It's not particularly clear what you are trying to achieve.  Please explain fully what your goal is so that we can help you figure the problem out?

Comment: I have a part of link in ColumnA. I want first code goes for RangeA1 then A2, A3 And it continue until found data in ColumnA

Comment: Not only do you want to dynamically change the part of link but you need to also change the destination ranges: B1. Please describe or show the row/col size of the resulting querytable data.

Comment: I no need to change destination ranges:B1. Because Data will be cut to sheet2 from Sheet1 before starting another loop.

Comment: So you want it to loop over column A from cell 1, until it finds data?  So if the data is in cell A56, cells A1-A55 are empty?  Once it finds data, you want it put into B1?  Is that correct?

Answer (score 0):

Try below code

```
    Dim rowID As Integer
    rowID = 1
    Do

        '<Your code>

        rowID = rowID + 1
    Loop Until Sheet1.Cells(rowID, 1).Value = ""
```

Credit goes to www.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Please tell me about this line ticjername = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

Comment: `ticjername = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value` gets the value of cell `"A1"` and stores in variable `ticjername`.

Comment: I tried with this. It loop but Always link goes for RangeA1 . I need to dynamic this line also.   ticjername = Sheet1.Range("A1").Value

Comment: Suppose I have data in Sheet1 column A1 to A5. So first it goes for A1. then A2, A3, A4 & A5